# Was the Pack's memory of eating the Principal ever mentioned again?

Tags: plot-explanation, buffy-the-vampire-slayer

In Buffy the Vampire Slayer Season 1 Episode 6, Xander and 4 other students are possessed and they eat a pig. At the end they are all freed of possession and Xander claims memory loss. However Giles tells him when they are alone that he knows Xander didn't lose his memory and I think Xander mentions this in a later season as well. My question is was the fact that 4 students killed and ate the Principal ever brought up again? I mean if Xander remembered eating the pig and being mean they should be in a bad mental condition when they remember killing and eating a human but I don't believe it's ever mentioned again. I'll take answers from any source of tv, comic, or interviews in the Buffyverse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Snyder [brings it up](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0004943/quotes) in The Puppet Show (1x09):

> That's the kind of wooly-headed liberal thinking that leads to being eaten.

Buffy also asks Wood if he had heard about what happened to Flutie in [Beneath You (7x02)](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Beneath_You).

Other than that I don't think it comes up much at all. We certainly never see those students again.

Comment: Thanks it always seemed strange to me that the Pack's memories of killing and eating the principle was never mentioned again. Big missed opportunity for story there in my opinion. After all a lot of villains were recurring characters from the first season.